# Cant get my flex items to wrap correctly. They are not lining up underneath the first row correctly

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

As you can see if you run my snippet, the second row is being positioned in the middle of literally nowhere for no reason that I can explain. I want it to be right underneath the first row with a 0.5rem gap. I want to achieve this while still keeping the height of the container as minimum 3 item heights like I have it. Please help

```css
.grid_product_images {
  --gpi-item-size: 6rem;
  --gpi-gap: 0.5rem;
  --gpi-columns: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--gpi-columns), 1fr); */
  gap: var(--gpi-gap);
  max-width: calc(calc(var(--gpi-item-size) * var(--gpi-columns)) + calc(var(--gpi-gap) * calc(var(--gpi-columns) + 1)));
  min-height: calc(calc(var(--gpi-item-size) * var(--gpi-columns)) + calc(var(--gpi-gap) * calc(var(--gpi-columns) + 1)));
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: var(--gpi-gap);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: grey;
}
.grid_product_images > div {
  width: var(--gpi-item-size);
  height: var(--gpi-item-size);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.grid_product_images .btn_add_image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0.1rem solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid_product_images'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class='add_image_container'>
    <button type='button' class='btn_add_image' id='btn_add_image'>+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `align-content: flex-start;` in your flex container.

[As per MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content)

> The CSS align-content property sets the distribution of space between
> and around content items along a flexbox's cross-axis or a grid's
> block axis.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the way it does cause of the `min-height` set on `.grid_product_images`. You can fix this by adding [`align-content: flex-start;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content)

```css
.grid_product_images {
  --gpi-item-size: 6rem;
  --gpi-gap: 0.5rem;
  --gpi-columns: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--gpi-columns), 1fr); */
  gap: var(--gpi-gap);
  max-width: calc(calc(var(--gpi-item-size) * var(--gpi-columns)) + calc(var(--gpi-gap) * calc(var(--gpi-columns) + 1)));
  min-height: calc(calc(var(--gpi-item-size) * var(--gpi-columns)) + calc(var(--gpi-gap) * calc(var(--gpi-columns) + 0)));
  padding: var(--gpi-gap);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: grey;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.grid_product_images>div {
  width: var(--gpi-item-size);
  height: var(--gpi-item-size);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid_product_images .btn_add_image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0.1rem solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid_product_images'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class='add_image_container'>
    <button type='button' class='btn_add_image' id='btn_add_image'>+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```